# Error: reading EKS Cluster (): couldn't find resource when running terraform plan

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks

My terraform file is as following.

- module eks version: 19.5.1

```js
data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_name
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = module.eks.cluster_name
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
}

module "eks" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "19.5.1" //19.0 version created the ingress security group for us
...}
```

When running 'terraform plan', I get the error:

```js
│ Error: reading EKS Cluster (ccc): couldn't find resource
│ 
│   with data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster,
│   on main.tf line 7, in data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster":
│    7: data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
│ 
╵
```

Comment: Why do you use data source to get info about the cluster, if you already have `module "eks"`?

Comment: If you haven't actually created the cluster yet (and you are intending to do so with this TF configuration), then the error is pretty self-explanatory: TF can't find the resource, because it doesn't exist. Data sources are intended to refer to pre-existing resources that are managed outside of TF (or at least outside of this TF configuration). You might find that the best approach is to have two separate TF configurations - one to manage the cluster, and one to manage the things that run on the cluster.

Comment: @Marcin thanks for your advice.  I removed the data source and get data from module "eks" and it works.

Comment: @lxop thank you for explaining this to me.  Now I know how it works.  I should use two separate TF configuration. thanks

Answer (score 8):

I added `depends_on` to my data column and it worked.

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "calocalc-cluster" {
  name = var.cluster_name
  depends_on = [module.eks.cluster_name]
}
```

Comment: The proper way is to use what @EdK said, but it won't work with the official TF image if you decide to use a docker as a runner in GitLab. So I used your solution and it works just fine.

Answer (score 5):

Try removing the data resources and using the following kubernetes provider:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command     = "aws"
    args = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", module.eks.cluster_name]
  }
}
```

Comment: Also the examples in https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/tree/master/examples show this

Comment: I've used this approach when testing my TF code but when I moved it to a pipeline that executes TF in a docker image, I got an error that "aws" command doesn't exists because the official TF docker image doesn't have aws cli.

Answer (score 2):

This is something I've also been dealing with lately and the reason behind this dependency is because the `terraform-aws-eks` module has this property `manage_aws_auth_configmap` that needs the kubernetes provider to connect to after the cluster has already been created. So the main issue you could be facing is when creating the cluster for the first time. The terraform code would always fail because of this circular dependency.

The easiest workaround is to comment out the code portion for the kubernetes provider and set `manage_aws_auth_configmap = false` on the first run. After the first execution you can enable the kubernetes provider and, just then, set `manage_aws_auth_configmap = true`.

If you want a code friendly workaround, you could attempt what I did here, where I created a bool variable `eks_auth_enable` with default value `false` and the following code

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  count = var.eks_auth_enable ? 1 : 0
  name = module.eks_cluster.cluster_name
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  count = var.eks_auth_enable ? 1 : 0
  name = module.eks_cluster.cluster_name
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = var.eks_auth_enable ? data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster[0].endpoint : "http://localhost"
  cluster_ca_certificate = var.eks_auth_enable ? base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster[0].certificate_authority[0].data) : "CERT"
  token                  = var.eks_auth_enable ? data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster[0].token : "TOKEN"
}

module "eks_cluster" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version = "19.15.3"
  ...
}
```

This would let you run the first time with `eks_auth_enable = false` on your `.tfvars` file and then re-run the exact same code with `eks_auth_enable = true`

Answer (score 0):

With a slight tweak to what Edk suggested in the threads (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75950287/11207358), to prevent the need for `token` which will need you to get `aws_eks_cluster_auth` data, you should use `aws-iam-authenticator`:

```
  kubernetes {
    host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)
    exec {
      api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
      command     = "aws-iam-authenticator"
      # This requires the aws-iam-authenticator to be installed locally where Terraform is executed
      args = ["token", "--cluster-id", module.eks.cluster_name]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing this

```
resource "null_resource" "execute_command" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
      aws eks get-token \
        --cluster-name ${module.eks.cluster_name} \
        --region ${var.region} \
        --profile ${var.profile} > eks_token.txt
    EOT
  }
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = module.eks.cluster_endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(module.eks.cluster_certificate_authority_data)

  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
    command     = "cat"
    args        = ["eks_token.txt"]
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained the why additionally to the how.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).