# terragrunt, eks-aws module and data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" fails during plan if cluster is not yet created

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks, terragrunt

I'm writing terragrunt code that should use terraform aws eks module to create the cluster and then use helm provider to install cert-manager and ingress-nginx there. If I create cluster first there's no problem. However, if nothing exists before the first terragrunt run-all plan I get

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on helm_provider.tf line 13, in provider "helm":
│   13:     host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
│
│ A data resource "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" has not been declared in the
│ root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on helm_provider.tf line 14, in provider "helm":
│   14:     cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority[0].data)
│
│ A data resource "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" has not been declared in the
│ root module.
╵
╷
│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on helm_provider.tf line 15, in provider "helm":
│   15:     token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
│
│ A data resource "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" has not been declared in
│ the root module.
╵
```

here's my terragrunt.hcl for installing addons

```
terraform {
  source = "../../../modules/k8s-addons"
}

include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

include "env" {
  path   = find_in_parent_folders("env.hcl")
  expose = true
}

inputs = {
  cluster_name = dependency.eks.outputs.cluster_name
}

dependency "eks" {
  config_path = "../eks"

  mock_outputs = {
    cluster_name     = "eks-cluster"
    cluster_endpoint = "https://eks-cluster.k8s.local"
    cluster_version  = "1.29"
  }
}

generate "helm_provider" {
  path      = "helm_provider.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents  = <<EOF

data "aws_eks_cluster" "eks" {
    name = "${dependency.eks.outputs.cluster_name}"
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "eks" {
    name = "${dependency.eks.outputs.cluster_name}"
}

provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
    cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority[0].data)
    token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
  }
}
EOF
}
```

I know I can exclude-dir when I run terragrunt run-all plan. I also tried to the method described here: [Error: reading EKS Cluster (): couldn't find resource when running terraform plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943331/error-reading-eks-cluster-couldnt-find-resource-when-running-terraform-pla/75950287#75950287) but it doesn't seem to work with terragrunt specifically (or I'm making a different error there).

what can I do to achieve my goal i.e. running terragrunt run-all plan with no resource created and it not failing?